# Select and add function to all links in a nav

Tags: javascript, frontend

I am trying to add a function to all of the links in my nav that will delay the link to the next page while the menu shuts using javascript.

This is my javascript, I know the querySelector part is wrong but I am unsure how to fix it;

```
document.querySelector(".nav-link-close").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(e.target.href)
        toggleNav(false);
        setTimeout(() => {
            const nextPage = e.target.href;
            window.location.href = nextPage;
        }, 1000)
    });
```

Thank you in advance to anyone willing to help.

Comment: If `nav-link-close` is the parent element, you could iterate over his children
`document.querySelector(".nav-link-close").children.forEach(...)`

If `nav-link-close` is one of your links that should listen to event, you must rewrite your code using `querySelectorAll`

Comment: I think a little bit more of context is needed: what is exactly the class `.nav-link-close` ? A temporary class that is added to a menu link when it needs to be closed? Could you add in your question the markup of the menu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) will get the first element with `nav-link-close` class, so you need to use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and loop through the elements and add the event.

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-link-close")
elements.forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(e.target.href)
        toggleNav(false);
        setTimeout(() => {
            const nextPage = e.target.href;
            window.location.href = nextPage;
        }, 1000)
    });
})
```

Comment: You made a mistake in your code.
I assume```querySelectorAll``` should be at first line

Comment: @DimaVak Yes, you are right, but I already point it out in my description above the code, but thanks anyway, just updated.

Comment: Great work, thank you so much!